# Is this posible in GR $g_{ab}g^{ab}=1$?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, trace

Metric tensor multiplied by its inverse. I always see this with different indices.

Answer (score 2):

Since $g_{ab}g^{cb}=\delta_a^c$ is the identity matrix, taking the trace gives $g_{ab}g^{ab}=D$ in a $D$-dimensional spacetime.

Comment: And spacetimes are defined as $D \geq 2$, so it won't be 1

Comment: Why the downvote?